# about cache in sql adapter of worklight

Tags: mysql, ibm-mobilefirst

I went through  training  material of worklight. came to know that the adapters in worklight  have the property of scalability. I saw that worklight adapters use cache to reduce number of hits on the database. how does this cache act in reducing the number of hits?

Answer (score 1):

The Scalability for SQL adapters is no longer supported in Worklight.

In past version of Worklight, you could have used the Worklight server to cache queries and results.

Before sending a query to the back-end you could have checked if the exact query was sent in the past (there was a parameter of how long to keep this cache) and return the result from the cache without invoking the back-end.